# How do I get my camera to update the same frame as my player sprite?

Tags: java, libgdx

In LibGDX I'm trying to have my OrthographicCamera follow the playersprite when I move it around. Currently, the playersprite gets updated first and then in the next frame the camera updates to the position of the playersprite in the previous frame. Here is an example:
https://i.imgur.com/wxJUizU.gifv

I have tried moving gameMap.render(cam) to the bottom of the method, but not only does it not solve my problem, it also places the map textures above the playersprite, so you won't be able to see the playersprite anymore when it moves under the map.

Here is the code for rendering the playersprite and camera:

```java
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;
    cam.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3;

    gameMap.render(cam);

    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().begin();
    player.draw(gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch());
    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().end();

    cam.position.x = player.getX() + (player.getWidth() / 2);
    cam.position.y = player.getY() + (player.getHeight() / 2);
    cam.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Bradley says you should split your logic into two parts: update and render

Create a `udpate()` method where you place all your things to update and call this method first in the `render()` method:

```
public void update(){
    //Update camera position
    cam.position.x = player.getX() + (player.getWidth() / 2);
    cam.position.y = player.getY() + (player.getHeight() / 2);
    //apply all updates to the camera before this the changed position won't apply to the camera
    cam.update();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    //First call the update method we created
    update();

    //Clear the Screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Render
    gameMap.render(cam);

    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().begin();
    player.draw(gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch());
    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().end();
}
```

---

You don't need to call:

```
cam.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;
cam.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3;
```

every frame. It's enough to call it ones in the create() method

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do that from now on. I guess it was because gameMap.render() was called after cam.update(). Also currently I wouldn't have to keep setting viewport height and weidth. But the 3 at the end will eventually be dynamic, so I have to be able to set it again later. But for now you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you want to break your logic into two sections:

- Update
- Render

So, before each frame you want to perform any pertinent calculations.
Your camera is currently updating late, because it isn't performing logic until after the gameMap has been updated.
For example:

```
// Perform logic and update the state
public void Update () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;
    cam.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3;

    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().begin();

    cam.position.x = player.getX() + (player.getWidth() / 2);
    cam.position.y = player.getY() + (player.getHeight() / 2);
}

// Draw map
public void Render () {
    gameMap.render(cam);

    player.draw(gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch());
    gameMap.getTiledMapRenderer().getBatch().end();

    cam.update();
}
```

I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, so I can't tell if this would run or not, but when working with frames in any game development situation, this is how you want to handle things.

Comment: The class that these methods are in, is extending a fully abstract class ApplicationAdapter. That class does not contain any method called update(). The method update() in your example is never used. Also, if I update the camera beforehand, I get the same results.

Comment: Abstract classes don't stop you from implementing your own methods. I'm not suggesting just updating the camera before hand, I'm suggesting you perform all the logic for drawing the map and the camera in its own thread, and do not draw until all logic has been completed. It's typically considered bad practice to update and draw in the same thread. I would change whatever your Main() function is to call update then render, or just call Update() in the first line of Render().

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you can't implement your own methods. What I am suggesting is that I'm fairly sure that you could achieve what I want, with just the methods from the LibGDX. But there are update() methods in other classes like Sprite and GameMap. Perhaps I should try and use those.